# Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04; KAlarm no longer working

Tags: 18.04, akonadi

It opens looking funny, with no alarm times showing.  There is an error message: "KAlarm cannot be used without Akonadi personal information management."  The software distribution center has something (unreviewed) called Akonadi Console, which doesn't look very promising.  I do have an /etc/arkonadi directory, but it is empty.  If KAlarm is no longer supported, is there some other Ubuntu-compatible scheduler available?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what features KAlarm provides and what you are looking for, but try installing `alarm-clock-applet` for simple alarms and reminders.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, if I do install Akonadi Console from the Ubuntu software distribution, then KAlarm does work. I tested it with an tiny alarm set for five minutes from its input, and that works.  However, although all my previously inputted alarms show up, all their times are "never".  It did not seem possible to simply edit them to put in the times they are to go off.  So, I ended up having to laboriously delete each alarm and re-entering it (with ) with desired start times and adjustment of recurrences.

One thing I don't know how to fix still is my recurring script executions.  It seems the configuration file for KAlarm (where is it?) needs to be told where to find the terminal for running the "home/silbar/***.script".

*Note added:* I was not able to find that configuration file either on my computer or on the web, even though the kde.org people have a web page entitled "Chapter 3. Configuring KAlarm". I now run the script with an entry in the crontab.

Comment: So where IS the KAlarm Configuration file? I can't find it anywhere on my computer.  There is no ~.kalarm file and nothing in /usr/share/ or /etc/.